# T-SQL Foreach row if column has value 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreach

I'm new in working with SQL queries and I'm trying to check if for each parent from the `Parents` table I have the age for all children from `Children` table. For example:

**Parents**

```
 Name        Id
John Smith   7
```

**Children**

```
Name            Age    ParentId
Sasha Smith     10       7
Johnny Smith     0       7
```

This is what I have so far:

```
create function fnCheckChildren(
    @parentId int
)
returns int
begin 
declare @allOk int

if(select count(1) from Children where ParentId=@parentId ) = 0
BEGIN
    SET @allOk =1  --default all are ok - parent has no children 
END
else
BEGIN
   --here is my missing part
END

return @allOk 
end
go
```

If I'll call the function for John Smith (@parentId = 7) @allOk should have the value 0 because one of his children (Johnny) has Age 0. If all had Age > 0 then @allOk should have 1.

Can anyone help me with it? As I understand, T-SQL doesn't support For Each...Next, and so on, so what alternatives do I have?

Comment: You can use a cursor, it’s a loop: http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/

Comment: Depending on the religious belief system(s) involved, an age of zero may be reasonable for newborns. Other systems consider one's age at birth to be one year old. `NULL` is a better indicator of unknown data than a magic number like `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a relative simple and efficient method:

```
select p.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from children c where c.parentid = p.id and c.age = 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from p;
```

You can make this a  function by simply doing:

```
create function fnCheckChildren(
    @parentId int
)
returns int
begin 
    if (exists (select 1 from children where parentid = @parentid and age = 0)
       )
    begin
        return(0);
    end;
    return(1);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for CURSOR at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parents p
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN
                      COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN c.Age > 0 THEN 1 END) THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END AS res
             FROM Children c
             WHERE p.id = c.parent_id
            ) sub
 -- WHERE ....;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36175e0011496039960ff434fd1b6328)**

> As I understand, T-SQL doesn't support For Each.

This is not true, For-Each is kind of correlated subquery for instance: using inline syntax like in [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611534/5070879) or `OUTER APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCheckChildren(
    @parentId INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
DECLARE @allOk INT

SET @allOk = CASE WHEN (select count(*) from Children where ParentId=@parentId AND Age > 0) > 1 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END

RETURN @allOk 
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a case of no children at all.  This will indicate that.

```
declare @P table (id int identity primary key, name varchar(20));
insert into @P (name) values ('John Smith'), ('Pat Jones'), ('Will Smith');
select * from @P;
declare @C table (id int identity primary key, parID int, name varchar(20), age int);
insert into @C (parID, name, age) values (1, 'jim', 12), (1, 'sally', 0), (2, 'bruce', 10);
select * from @C; 
select p.id, P.name 
     , count(c.id) as [child count]
     , case when MIN(c.age) <= 0 then 'childen with zero' else 'no children with zero' end as status
from @P p 
left join @C c 
on p.id = c.parID 
group by p.id, p.name;
```